# TautologyQ like feature that also works for inequalities

Tags: expression-test, boolean-computation, logic

If a=b and b=c, then a=c.

So in mathematica,

```
TautologyQ[(a == b) && (b == c) \[Implies] a == c, {a, b, c}]
```

yields 'True'.

If a<b and b<c, then a<c. (if a,b,c are elements of an ordered set)

But

```
TautologyQ[(a < b) && (b < c) \[Implies] a < c, {a, b, c}]
```

does not yield 'True'. Instead it yields an error message '...is not Boolean valued...', Because < is not a boolean expression.

Is there a built-in feature in mathematica similar to `TautologyQ`, which yields `True` for the latter code ?

My question can be restated as following :
'extend TautologyQ to include inequality symbol'

If it is possible, I want to go further and further. (first include some  basic calcuation symbol like +,-,*,/,mod, then function defining and composition, ...)

Comment: `Simplify[(a < b) && (b < c) \[Implies] a < c, {a, b, c}]` or `Simplify[(a < b) && (b < c) \[Implies] a < c, Element[_, Reals] ]` yield True.

Comment: I think in `TautologyQ[expr, {a,b,c}]` the variables `{a,b,c}` are boolean, not numeric. Therefore `a < b` doesn't make sense (within that domain). You might want something like `Reduce[(a < b) && (b < c) \[Implies] a < c, {a, b, c}, Reals]`.

Comment: @MarcoB I think it could be argued that your first `Simplify` accidentally gives the desired answer, but the second one looks good.  See what happens if you execute `Simplify[(a < b) && (b < c) \[Implies] a < c, {a}]`.

Comment: This is the sort of thing `Resolve` using quantifiers is intended to handle. `In[618]:= Resolve[
 ForAll[{a, b, c}, Implies[(a < b) && (b < c), a < c]]]

Out[618]= True`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, the first form of Simplify is iffy, I agree.

Comment: Thank you. If one of you want to get some stackexchange points you can answer this question!